# .htaccess redirect dynamic URLs to new system

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cgi

I've got an old CGI/Perl based news system that generated URLs like this (only the bit after id= changes / is dynamic):

https://www.mysite.co.uk/cgi-bin/news/viewnews.cgi?id=EEyulAFAAESQUwZyzN

I've since deleted that system and uploaded the database to a new PHP based script that retains the same id= codes for articles.

https://www.mysite.co.uk/news/EEyulAFAAESQUwZyzN.html

The question is, how can I redirect all the calls to the old dynamic URL structure to the new one?